# Migrations failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I have two migrations.. the self.down method is failing on one and working on the other even though they seem identical to me (different tables, same columns and types.)  If I replace :string with "varchar(255)" it works, but I don't understand why :string would fail in this case.

Can somebody see what I might be doing wrong?

I'm using Rails / ActiveRecord 2.1.0 and Mysql 5.6.13 on OSX

This one fails.

```
  def self.down
    remove_column :comments, :employee_id
    add_column :comments, :employee_id, :string #"varchar(255)" will work 
    Comment.all.each do |c|
      c.employee_id = c.empno
      c.send(:update_without_callbacks)
     end
    remove_column :comments, :empno
  end
```

This one works

```
  def self.down
    remove_column :supervisor_options, :employee_id
    add_column :supervisor_options, :employee_id, :string
    SupervisorOption.all.each do |c|
      c.employee_id = c.empno
      c.send(:update_without_callbacks)
     end
    remove_column :supervisor_options, :empno
  end
```

The stack I get during db:migrate is...

```
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(255)' at line 1: ALTER TABLE `comments` ADD `employee_id` varchar(255)(255)
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:147:in `log'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-mysql2-adapter-0.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:265:in `execute'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-mysql2-adapter-0.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:450:in `add_column'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:330:in `send'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:330:in `method_missing'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:310:in `say_with_time'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:310:in `say_with_time'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:326:in `method_missing'
./db/migrate//20140501155627_rename_employee_id.rb:17:in `down_without_benchmarks'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:264:in `send'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:264:in `migrate'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:264:in `migrate'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:430:in `migrate'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:420:in `each'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:420:in `migrate'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:361:in `down'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:341:in `migrate'
/Users/gakins/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gaimplan/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/tasks/databases.rake:99
```

Comment: Are you sure `:employee_id` is meant to be a string?  It sounds like it would be an integer column.  Also, the failing sql (according to your stack trace) is `ADD employee_id varchar(255)(255)` - where is the extra (255) coming from?  What are you actually calling when you get this error? Is it the line with the comment at the end, or with the "varchar(255)" uncommented, ie included?

Comment: I'm migrating an existing database; the employee_id as a string is already there and I'm restructing the database so employee_id is a proper foreign key and empno is a string .. however the down has to turn employee_id back to a string.   No clue where the extra 255 is coming from nor why the exact same migration works for a different table.

Comment: 'ALTER TABLE `comments`'. why is the error message referring to the comments table? I thought it was `:supervisor_options` table that's failing

Comment: Why both statements in same method as down `remove_column :comments, :employee_id`
`add_column :comments, :employee_id, :string`